# Return name after clicking button - HTML, PHP, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML file with a text input field and a button. When you type a name and click the button, it should return the name you typed within the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get() {
        $.post('data.php', { name: form.name.value},
            function(output) {
            $('#age').html(output).show();
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <form name="form">
            <input type ="text" name="name">
            <input type="button" value="get" onClick="get();">
        </form>
    </p>

    <div id="age"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a PHP file, data.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST('name');
    echo $name;
?>
```

It should return the name I typed in the div, but it doesn't work. Anyone tips?

Comment: change naming conventions.. name elements normally

Comment: See this is wrong `$name = $_POST('name');` this is correct `$name = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: One thing I picked up on is that you have no method of getting the form in `form.name.value`, I would suggest sending `this.form` to the function and collecting that as a `form` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form">
    <input type ="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get" name ="submit" />
</form>
<div id="age"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('form[name="form"]').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).find('input[name="name"]').val();
        $.post('data.php', { name: name}, function(output) {
            $('#age').html(output);
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP:** (But it just prints name back, not age but this is right way, not `$name = $_POST('name');`
)

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name; // output in ajax success will be name value
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
```